# Position group footer at bottom of page

Tags: crystal-reports

My last group footer is designed to appear at the bottom of the page. When I run a single report everything is kept on one page it looks just fine.

When I run multiple instances of the report, this group footer prints at the bottom of the second page but everything before is completely blank - even when there is plenty of room on the first page. When I uncheck *Print at Bottom of Page*, the footer appears at the top of the second page (even if is plenty of space on the first.)

How can I standardize this behavior?

Comment: Can you include some screenshots? It's a little difficult to tell what you want just from the description.

Comment: Unfortunately it is pretty sensitive information, I'll try to explain a little better. I have 10 group footers, all of them print perfectly together on one page when running 1 invoice on the report. Once I run 2 or more invoices at once on the report, the last group footer always prints on the bottom of another page with nothing but blank space before it. There is plenty of room for the group footer to fit on the 1 page, like it does when I run 1 invoice. So if I run 4 invoices, I am getting 8 pages, 4 with the content and 4 with my last group footer at the bottom of a blank page. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried activating New Page After for the footer? (You can blackout the information in the screenshots - It just might help to see it in action. There might be something in the layout we can correct.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest.. Adjust your footer and use suppress then run your application again if theres any improvement changes happen;

it look like this

[image]